# Magento Event Before Adding a Product to Cart

Tags: php, events, magento

I want to calculate price based on the customer selected options.
For example,there are two configurable attributes `length,width`

Before adding product to cart,I want to modify price based on selected length & width

```
$finalPrice=$rrp+($length*$width)
```

Is there any event available to achieve this?

Comment: Already tried `sales_quote_add_item`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would look at `catalog_product_get_final_price`, and for an example usage, see [`Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php#L92). Note that options-based pricing is processed after this event; see [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php#L74) and [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price::getFinalPrice()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php#L43).

Please keep in mind that customizing this functionality requires lots of testing with different quote states, customer states, product types, etc. For example, consider a product which is added to the cart for the first time, then having its quantity updated from the cart. Often it is necessary to implement logic in a couple of methods/observers to handle all permutations.

Full list for events fired in CE1.7 when customer not logged in, new cart, simple product:

**controller_front_init_routers**

- `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router::initControllerRouters()`

**controller_action_predispatch**

- `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::initByRequest()`
- `Mage_PageCache_Model_Observer::processPreDispatch()`
- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::emulateQuote()`
- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session::renewCookie()`
- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::checkExpirePersistentQuote()`
- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::emulateCustomer()`

**catalog_product_load_after**

- `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::addInventoryData()`

**custom_quote_process**

- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::setLoadPersistentQuote()`

**sales_quote_config_get_product_attributes**

- `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer::addProductAttributes()`

**prepare_catalog_product_collection_prices**

- `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::prepareCatalogProductCollectionPrices()`

**sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load**

- `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::addInventoryDataToCollection()`

**sales_quote_item_qty_set_after**

- `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty()`

**sales_quote_collect_totals_before**

- `Mage_Tax_Model_Observer::quoteCollectTotalsBefore()`

**sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before**

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::changeQuoteCustomerGroupId()`

**sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after**

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::restoreQuoteCustomerGroupId()`

**sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before**

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::changeQuoteCustomerGroupId()`

**catalog_product_get_final_price**

- `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()`

**sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after**

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::restoreQuoteCustomerGroupId()`

**sales_quote_collect_totals_after**

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::setQuoteCanApplyMsrp()`

**sales_quote_save_before**

- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::setQuotePersistentData()`

**sales_quote_save_after**

- `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer::salesQuoteSaveAfter()`
- `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::bindQuoteCreate()`

**sales_quote_item_save_before**

- `Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer::checkoutCartAddProduct()`

**checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

- `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Observer::processAddToCart()`

**controller_action_postdispatch**

- `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor::saveByRequest()`

**controller_front_send_response_after**

- `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer_Session::synchronizePersistentInfo()`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.Just adding to what you've said, I've looked into `catalog_product_get_final_price`.This event sets the base price of a configurable product even before choosing the options.

Comment: Yep. Depending on your product types, discount activities, and custom pricing logic, it can be quite involved to "do something" in this space :-/

Comment: If you end up observing on any of the add-to-cart functions be warned that the state of the data varies if the quote object is new or not (first item in quote or not). Quite annoying. Also, as ben commented, be conscious of the discount modules. Be sure to add them as dependencies to ensure your observer triggers after. Easier to handle their logic than assume they will handle yours.