# Custom error message on Product page in Magento

Tags: magento

I've created an observer and I need to populate the messages_product_view div on the product page when a specific event happens. How can I go about populating this div? Below is a screenshot of the area that I need to populate.

[screenshot here](http://cl.ly/image/262x3P2I0i2c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Magento Session models i.e. core/session, customer/session etc.

To add a message you can use for example:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message); // Add green success message
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message); // Add red error message
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice($message); // Add yellow notice message
```

Template files have a call to the following which renders the session messages. Look for this:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Messages can also be retrieved manually like so:

```
$messages = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true);
foreach($messages->getItems() as $message)
{ 
   $message->getText();
   //...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Message is being displayed in that block. However, I'm executing from an Observer (listening to a custom before add to cart event), and I need to stop the add to cart action, in addition to outputting that custom message. My guess was Mage::throwException, but that threw out some nasty error messages. If I use Mage::throwException before, the add to cart is added except it bypasses the message and redirects the user to an exception error page. Any thoughts? Almost there :)

Comment: Where have you placed your custom event? Have a look at the addAction() of Mage_Checkout_CartController. Ideally you want to detect your error and follow the _goBack() functionality to redirect the user before adding the item and saving the quote. 

Have a look here for a list of "out of the box" add to cart events you might be able to hook into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12531332/651529

Comment: I created an observer that dispatches a custom event, or multiple if I wish. I'll take a look at the provided link. Thanks for all your help!